# Not able to change padding of material UI Select component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm struggling to override the default padding of the Select component to match the size of my other text fields. I understand that I need to modify nested components but have been unable to find a working solution.

```
<div className='wifi-chooser-column'>
<TextField
    style={{margin: '6px'}} 
    label='SSID' 
    variant='outlined'
    size='small'
/>
<Select
    style={{margin: '6px', padding: '0px'}}
    variant='outlined'
    value={this.state.security}
    onChange={(event) => this.setState({security: event.target.value})}
    classes={{
        select: {
            padding: '10.5px 14px'
        }
    }}
>
    <MenuItem label='security' value='Unsecured'>Unsecured</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value='WEP'>WEP</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value='WPA2'>WPA2</MenuItem>
</Select>
<TextField 
    style={{margin: '6px'}} 
    label='Username' 
    variant='outlined'
    size='small'
/>
<TextField 
    style={{margin: '6px'}} 
    label='Password' 
    variant='outlined'
    size='small'
/>
```

[Layout issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgp2g.png)

Comment: Can you provide a CodeSandbox with your code please?

Answer (score 7):

[According to the doc](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/), there are several ways that we can override the material UI component styles.

If we want to override the padding of the `Select` components differently and occasionaly, or if this process would not be repeated in the entire project, we can simply use  [Overriding styles with classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes) approach. In this way, first we need to create our desired padding for Select component by `makeStyles` as below:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  rootFirstSelect: {
    padding: "4px 0px"
  },
  rootSecondSelect: {
    padding: "10px 80px"
  }
}));
```

and then assign it to the `classes` prop of the component, by modifying the root element:

```
    const classes = useStyles();
    //Other part of the code
    return (
    //Other part of the code

    <Select
      classes={{ root: classes.rootFirstSelect }}
    //other props
    >

    //Other part of the code

    )
```

[working sandbox example for this method](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0lmo0?file=/demo.js:968-1174)

If we want to override the padding of the `Select` component for the whole project, [Global theme variation](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#5-global-theme-variation) would prevent repetition. In this way, we should create a theme by `createMuiTheme`, as below, and apply our desired changes there:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSelect: {
      select: {
        padding: "4px 0px 10px 130px !important"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

then pass this theme as a prop to the `ThemeProvider` component which surround the whole project:

```
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Demo />
  </ThemeProvider>
```

[working example in sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8ltkc?file=/index.js:331-392)

Comment: ```classes={{ root: classes.root }}```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found an alternative way in the docs, that's easier to use for me: instead of using Select component, I use TextField with "select" props

cf: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#select

```
<TextField
  id="standard-select-currency"
  select
  label="Select"
  value={currency}
  onChange={handleChange}
  helperText="Please select your currency"
>
  {currencies.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

Which allows you to access TextField props such as margin="none", margin="dense"

Comment: Can then add size="small" in TextField. That gets the job done for me. Thnx.